# What is the zipped type of this encoded string?

Tags: javascript, cordova, zip, deflate, inflate

My brothers give me a sqlite file. It comes with some fields that its values was encoded like this: `X'737AB86B719E82CBC3DDDDC9190ABE0F77CFCE54303230300200'` (all of it has `X'` prefix) and I don't know what type of this string. Any one know the name of this algorithm? And how to decode it into normal string (readable) in javascript?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is raw deflate data.  You can use [zlib](http://zlib.net/) to decompress it.

That string decompresses to this, in hexadecimal:

```
42 e1 ba a3 6e 20 44 e1 bb 8b 63 68 20 4d e1 bb
9b 69 20 32 30 30 32
```

or this as a UTF-8 string:

> Bản Dịch Mới 2002

Here is a [port of zlib to native javascript](https://github.com/nodeca/pako).

Comment: Thanks you so much.
But can you show me how to decompress that string to hexadecimal?
Please explain more details how you did that for me, please!

Comment: can you show me how to use inflate function of the pako library? I try input below string `X'737AB86B719E82CBC3DDDDC9190ABE0F77CFCE54303230300200' ` but it didn't work.
Like this: `var data = pako.inflateRaw("737AB86B719E82CBC3DDDDC9190ABE0F77CFCE54303230300200");`

Comment: It's being displayed to you in hexadecimal.  You have to convert the hexadecimal to binary before feeding it to a decompressor.  You can search here on stackoverflow for how to do that conversion in javascript.

Comment: Thanks. I found a solution.

Answer (score 0):

have you try to see the schema used sqlite?

```
sqlite> .schema
```

to find out what's the fields type data inside. Because that's string look like BLOB type fields.

If you just want to extract the files from table (stdout) you can do this methods

```
SELECT writefile('filename.jpg',img) FROM tableName WHERE id='1';
```

the example is about to fill out data from tables to file (stdout). ***SELECT writefile*** to write file out from your table, ***filename.jpg*** it's example files contain inside tables, ***img*** that's string your have on this question contain files in BLOB type, ***FROM tableName*** replace with your tableName, ***WHERE id='1'*** match it with id of strings you want to exec.

Comment: Yes. It is `image` type in sqlite. But I don't know how to use it. Can you give me a suggestion how to read it in javascript?

Comment: Thanks for your help @ian. But my brother he said the original data is the normal text string. Then he compress as an image and save it to sqlite database.
My duty is to convert it back to original string (not image file).